# Кликабельный текст в Toolbar

Tags: android, actionbar, android-toolbar, android-on-click

Подскажите пожалуйста следующее, есть много фрагментов и по клику текста (имя проекта) в `toolbar`'е должен показывать главный фрагмент. Как сделать этот текст кликабельным или куда копать хотя бы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    ...>

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
         ... />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**В классе:**

```
toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Clicked");
        }
});
```

*P.S. Убрать основное название и добавить его в*`TextView`.

Comment: Разве так делают?) Я имею ввиду тот текст который по умолчанию ставится как имя проекта, его же не обязательно в `TextView` прописывать?

Comment: @T.Kudaibergen ну я не вижу препятствий:) основу для копания я дал, надеюсь) А вообще делают и еще не такое)

Comment: К сожалению это не то, в туулбаре рядом с основным тайтлом создается еще текст, мне же нужно получить доступ к основному тайтлу

Comment: @T.Kudaibergen убрать основной текст и поместить textview?

Comment: Вот оно как) Я то думал есть спец метод для этого) Большое спасибо

Comment: @T.Kudaibergen да я сам подробно не дал ответ, исправлю) Рад был помочь!:)